# Calculate Time and insert in array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app the read values from external devices. After this, these values are written in the database.

I have values like acceleration, gyroscope, magnetometer and pressure.

The acceleration, gyroscope and magnetometer are read together with a time in this way:

(for example for acceleration)

```
const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [time, ...acc] = [0,2,4,6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({
          time,
          acc,
          array_acc_sx: [
            ...state.array_acc_sx, 
            [time , acc ]  
          ]
        }));
```

For the pressure I can't do the same, because the pressure doesn't have the time automatically.

So I have think set a variable timeP equal to the time of the acc,gyr,mag.

But in this way the set time starts before the reading of values of pressure, so the result is something like this:

```
   "PL":
     "[740,740,740,740,700,700,660,660,580,580,580,
560,500,500,500,500,500,440,400,400,340,340,320,300,
280,260,260,260,200,180,160,160,140,
// there start the time + pressure values.
[140,[0,0,0,0,0]],[160,[0,0,0,0,0]],[160,[0,0,0,0,0]],
[180,[0,0,0,0,0]],[200,[0,0,0,0,0]],[260,[0,0,0,0,0]],
[260,[0,0,0,0,0]],[260,[0,0,0,0,0]],[280,[0,0,0,0,0]],
[300,[0,0,0,0,0]],[320,[0,0,0,0,0]],[340,[0,0,0,0,0]],
[340,[0,0,0,0,0]],[400,[0,0,0,0,0]],[400,[0,0,0,0,0]],
[440,[0,0,0,0,0]],[500,[0,0,0,0,0]],[500,[0,0,0,0,0]],
.....
```

this is the code that I used:

```
async setupNotifications2(device) {
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    /* Accelerometro + Giroscopio + Magnetometro */
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.AccGyrMg,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [time, ...acc] = [0,2,4,6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({
          time,
          acc,
          array_acc_sx: [
            ...state.array_acc_sx, 
            [time , acc ]  
          ]
        }));

        //console.log("this.state.time - ", this.state.time)
        this.setState({timeP: this.state.time})


        const [ ...gyr] = [8,10,12].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({
          time,
          gyr,
          array_gyr_sx: [
            ...state.array_gyr_sx, 
            [time, gyr]
          ]
        }));

        const [ ...mg] = [14,16,18].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({
          time,
          mg,
          array_mg_sx: [
            ...state.array_mg_sx, 
            [time, mg]
          ]
        }));

      }
    );

    /* Pressione */
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.Pressure,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log("TimeP - ", this.state.timeP)
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...pressure_sx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => buf.readUInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({...state.timeP, pressure_sx,array_pressure_sx: [this.state.timeP, ...state.array_pressure_sx, [this.state.timeP, pressure_sx] ]
        }));
      }
    );
```

In your opinion how can I do to solve this kind of problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setInterval() function to record the time of each state:

```
var Time = 0;

function resetT()
{
Time=0;
clearInterval(stateT)
console.log("state_reset")
}

function stateInitiate(t)
{
//t will be your unit of time (1 = a millisecond, 1000 = a second)
setInterval(stateT,t)
}

function stateT()
{
 Time++;
}

function init()
{
device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.Pressure,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log("TimeP - ", Time)//variable time
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...pressure_sx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => buf.readUInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({...state.timeP, pressure_sx,array_pressure_sx: [this.state.timeP, ...state.array_pressure_sx, [this.state.timeP, pressure_sx] ]
        }));
      }
    );
stateInitiate(1)//adds 1ms every ms
}
init()//begin sequence
```

Let me know if this was what you were looking for...  :)

Comment: it's what I'm searching to do :(

Comment: oh ok, from your example, it seems you might be able to :), can you somehow create a variable logging the time constant?

Comment: I have try to use "this.setState({timeP: this.state.time})" but the result is not correct. Do you have some idea? :)

Comment: Actually, are you trying to log the time taken from when the state has begun to when the state is to change?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to create a setInterval() when the state is created that counts up each millisecond. Then you can call this variable to see how long it took for the state to change... If not, then the only other thing would be to console.log the this.state variable and see what is inside it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about the second answer did you refer to time that I used in the acceleration?

Comment: Yes, so in the acceleration, gyro or mag states you might be able to source the time from these. You would be able to use the time as a reference for if the time is in seconds or milliseconds, which could be used in my first answer to get the time you want :) Ill edit my answer and show you what I mean :)

Comment: Thank for your answer :) I have tried but it prints me "null" in the array

Comment: In any of the states? maybe try listing it in a variable?

Comment: I tried it only in the pressure like in your example

Comment: Oh, did you use my answer example and the variable 'Time' is returning null?